# Distinct values between two SQL queries

Tags: sql, select, subquery, distinct

I want to be able to find any potential differences between data inputted on one day to another.

The relevant col. from the table are seen below:

```
Name | Size | DateSale | Location | Comments | Date
```

The two current queries are:

```
Select Name, Size, DateSale, Location, Comments from [Table] where Date = '06/02/2022'
Select Name, Size, DateSale, Location, Comments from [Table] where Date = '06/01/2022'
```

How would I come up with a list of values that are different from these two lists? Tried working with select distinct but could not figure it out.

Sample Data:

```
 Name | Size | DateSale | Location | Comments | Date
 john | 100  |06/05/2022| Houston  | proj.    | 06/02/2022
 john | 100  |06/04/2022| Dallas   |          | 06/01/2022
 jake | 90   |06/04/2022| Houston  | proj.    | 06/02/2022
 jake | 90   |06/04/2022| Houston  | proj.    | 06/01/2022
```

Desired Result:

```
 john | 100  |06/05/2022| Houston  | proj.    | 06/02/2022
```

Since the keys (Name + Size) are the same, but there are differences in the other categories (Sale Date, Location, or Comments), it will return
the row from the first query (most recent date)

Comment: What RDBMS?  What do you mean by "different from these two lists"? Sample data and desired result would go a long way here.

Comment: Added sample data/result in question

Comment: Using MS SQL (SSMS)

Comment: Very confusing, do you want distinct rows, differences, common in both queries, or most recent?

Comment: Rows where the Name and Size (identifying information) are the same, but Date of Sale, Location, and Comment are distinct

Comment: You have basically answered your own question.  Join on the keys, in your where clause check to see where one or more of the columns are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT y.* FROM (SELECT * from Table where Date = '05/31/2022') as x, 
(SELECT * FROM Table where DATE = '06/02/2022') as y where x.Name = y.Name 
and x.Size = y.Size and (x.DateSale!=y.DateSale or x.Location!=y.Location or 
x.COMMENTS != y.COMMENTS)
```

This solution worked for me